# Scala Slick can't union queries with count

Tags: scala, slick

I have two `Slick` queries which return `count` by filter, they look like this:

```
val firstCount = query.filter(_.someCond).length
val secondCount = query.filter(_.someCond).length
val unionCount = firstCount union secondCount //Place with the problem
```

Slick can make union for single queries without count - which return `Rep[Int]` instead of `QueruBase`.

My target is to take `firstCount` and `secondCount` during one sql query.

Comment: I guess you could do: `val a1 = q1.length.result; val a2 = q2.length.result; val action = DBIO.sequence(Seq(a1, a2))` and extract first and second result...

Comment: Above wouldn't actually do it in a single query though (as specified in question).

Comment: How about `val unionCount = (query.filter(_.someCond) union query.filter(_.someCond)).length`?

Comment: @Pawel Dolega i would like to something like this in sql: `select count(1) from some_table union select count(1) from some_table`

Comment: @Roman my target is taking two `lengths` - from first and second query as two int parameter, i don't need one length of union both of them

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, I can see you won't like this but that's the only way that I could figure out without too long of an investigation.

*This is more of a workaround than the solution.* @insan-e solution (simply use two queries) might be actually more feasible (IMHO it is - but I don't know your constraints).

Here is the query:

```
    TABLE1
      .filter(_.someColumn === "1stFilterValue") // your filter basically
      .map(_ => LiteralColumn(1))
      .union {
        TABLE2
          .filter(_.someColumn === "2ndFilterValue") // again your filter
          .map(_ => LiteralColumn(2))
      }.groupBy { marker =>
        marker
      }.map { case (marker, grouped) =>
        (marker, grouped.length)
      }
```

This would produce following query (assuming that I have column `name` - used for filtering):

```
select x2, count(1) 
from (
    select 1 as x2 
    from "TABLE1" 
    where "NAME" = 'Mike' 
    union 
    select 2 as x2 
    from "TABLE2" 
    where "NAME" = 'Tom'
 ) 
 group by x2
```

this would return following results:

```
DEBUG s.j.J.benchmark - Execution of prepared statement took 50ms
DEBUG s.j.S.result - /----+----------\
DEBUG s.j.S.result - | 1  | 2        |
DEBUG s.j.S.result - | X2 | COUNT(1) |
DEBUG s.j.S.result - |----+----------|
DEBUG s.j.S.result - | 1  | 1        |
DEBUG s.j.S.result - | 2  | 1        |
DEBUG s.j.S.result - \----+----------/
```

Keep in mind that particular row won't appear in results if count for it is equal 0 (no rows). You'd need to handle this in your code!

Comment: I already have tried solution like this - `select x2, count(1) 
from (
    select 1 as x2 
    from "TABLE1" 
    where "NAME" = 'Mike' 
    union 
    select 2 as x2 
    from "TABLE2" 
    where "NAME" = 'Tom'
 ) 
 group by x2
`  It's wrong, for instance, if i have thousands rows in `x2`, in result i will have thousands of count instead of single.

Comment: I am not sure what are you saying above. You will have two results right? One count for one query (first part of the union), the other for second query (second part of the union). Isn't this what you wanted to have?

Basically the results are two counts identified by whatever marker you pick (above marker is `1` and `2`).